# ASP.NET with ADFS and STS authentication

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, adfs

I have set up authentication using adfs and sts withh single sign on. How can i customise login screen for adfs to allow a "Remember Me" functionality so that to make it easier for the user?

Is there a way of say having form-authentication set up within the application and then sending he user's username and password from the application to the sts site? That is, I have a login form (with the "remember me" control) and upon login in, sending the credentials to my sts site for authentication. That way, the application can store the username and password needed for authentication.

Comment: do a google search on `Aspx Remember Me` I know there are plenty of examples that exist out there on the internet to this day..

Comment: What version of ADFS?